# How to remove underline from text-input in textarea?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using different types of fonts in textarea. But when I start typing(in android), the text which I type is underlined until I hit space and than again the next word is underlined and so on. How to remove this underline? I tried `text-decoration: none;` but its not working.

**HTML**

```
<ion-row class="text-row ion-justify-content-center">
    <ion-textarea #textBlock id="textId" (ionBlur)="focusText()" [(ngModel)]="textBlockData.text" rows="1" maxRows="15"
      style="
        font-size: {{ textBlockData.fontSize }}px;
        font-family: {{ textBlockData.fontFamily }};
        color: {{ textBlockData.color }};" class="text-input" (resized)="onResized($event)"
      placeholder="Write something" autosize>
    </ion-textarea>
</ion-row>
```

**SCSS**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Pacifico;
  src: url("../../../../assets/fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url("../../../../assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
}

.text-input {
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  max-height: 500px;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok its a spell checker in android keyboard. Turning that OFF removes the line. I got answer from [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-remove-the-underline-feature-while-typing-in-Android-keyboard)

Comment: Thats for XML not CSS

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `!important` to your text decoration.

```
.text-input {
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  max-height: 500px;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Add the same `text-decoration: none !important;` to `.text-row` and if it still doesn't work, I guess the line isn't an underline. So you try others like `outline: none` and `border: none`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
outline:none
```

to remove underline from inuputs